# Iphone When does Operation Queue Thread Really Start?

Tags: iphone, multithreading, cocoa-touch

When trying code that looks like this, mainly for testing

---

```
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [NSInvocationOperation alloc];
operation = [operation initWithTarget:self 
                             selector:@selector(dosignup:) 
                               object:params];   

while ( ![operation isFinished] ) [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];

[operation release];
```

---

The dosignup never gets called.  So then I have to assume that the selector does not get called until the main thread processes this, not at time of queue insert like a fork and / or a thread on .NET...  Anyway to force the queue to processes the thread?

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add your operation to a NSOperationQueue or you have to start it manually.

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(dosignup:) object:params];
[queue addOperation:operation];
[operation release];

[queue release];
```

or

```
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(dosignup:) object:params];
[operation start];
```

---

But I don't know what you really want to do, because your code makes only little sense right now.

Comment: Also watch the queue release on the top example, make sure you don't pre-release the queue, ok on the operation.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call `[operation start]` for it to execute. Be aware that the `NSInvocationOperation` is non-concurrent so it will execute synchronously and not spawn a thread. This means that your current implementation is roughly equal to this code:

```
[self dosignup:params];
```